# Maven uses dependencies from workspace not .m2 folder

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency

So I have the following [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLnTI.png) Sporium is a working set with the maven multimodule `spigot-parent` my problem now is when I define this [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/4F3Nbwq1) in my project it will not use the created dependency in the `.m2` folder but instead it will use the files in the maven module project of my IDE's workspace which doesn't work because they are raw, unpatched and uncompiled files
as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUhl8.png). Any idea how I can tell maven to not use the version in my workspace and only search in the local repo `.m2` folder?

Comment: The default in Eclipse is to make workspace resolution and follow the guidance of J Fabian Meier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project, choose "Maven" and then disable Workspace resolution.

Then the projects are not resolved from your workspace any more.